# Different image in different theme or style

Tags: android, image, themes, styles, android-styles

I have activity A and activity B. They both use the the same layout but they have different theme. Now defining different properties for example textColor is done like this

```
<item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
```

but I want to do something different. I want to have different images for "ImageView01" element

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:background="@drawable/attachment1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
```

the "ImageView01" is present in activity A and B. but I want to have different image for element "ImageView01" in A and different image for element "ImageView01" in activity B.

is this possible at all ?

Comment: I found my answer
here is the link
http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

In your inResume() methods have in Activity A:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.attachment1);
```

and in Activity B

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.attachment2);
```

Comment: :-) I do not know if I explain good but the thing that I want to achieve is to have something like iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.attachment_); for both cases. I want to have the same code and the magic should happen in the theme. I mean I want to find a way to tall which image to use in the theme not in the code

Comment: I do not know if it is possible, that is why I asked